# How can I add two texts in a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I'm encountering an issue with the SQL COUNT function that I need assistance with. Here's the scenario:

In my database, I have two records with values '-try' and '-try2.' However, when I use the COUNT function in my SQL query, it returns 1 instead of the expected 2.

I've attempted to modify the query using the expression VALUES ('text1' || ' ' || 'text2');, but it doesn't seem to affect the count as intended.

This is the example in fiddle

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
value_column VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO example_table (value_column) VALUES
('-try'),
('-try2');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example_table;
```

This example works like i wanted to.

its says two in one column

but in my column ist like this

```
<p>-try</p> <p>-try2</p>
```

idk how in the example works

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
value_column VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO example_table (value_column) VALUES
('<p>-try</p>''<p>-try2</p>');

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example_table;
```

Comment: Your value expression works as expected. https://dbfiddle.uk/Z-XWx91L You are not telling the whole story. To be honest,I am not sure what the story is at all. Please try to make your question clear. And disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to tell us. There are two strings in your database, '-try' and '-try2'? They are in the same table? In the same column or in the same row? You are using count on a table that has two rows, but the result says there is only one row in the table? You are using an expression that concatenates three string literals to a single string? What does that have to do with the aforementioned strings in the table and the counting? All this doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S9ZOHCkV) to demo the issue.

Comment: i dont how to explain, im sorry.

Comment: I think i understand how it works,  
-- This is 1 (one record)
INSERT INTO example_table (value_column) VALUES
('<p>-try</p><p>-try2</p>');

-- This is 2 (two records)
INSERT INTO example_table (value_column) VALUES
('-try'), ('-try2');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This INSERT statement creates one record:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (value_column) 
VALUES ('<p>-try</p>''<p>-try2</p>');
```

The content of this record is this: `<p>-try</p>'<p>-try2</p>`

If you want to insert two records, you need ( and ) and a comma , :

```
INSERT INTO example_table (value_column) 
VALUES ('<p>-try</p>')
      ,('<p>-try2</p>');
```

Comment: ok, thanks for your help 
and im sorry for not explaining myself well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store multiple values in a column, use an array type.
To get the count of things in the array, sum the length of those arrays:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value_column text[] -- define column as an array
);

INSERT INTO example_table (value_column) VALUES
('{<p>-try</p>, <p>-try2</p>}');

SELECT sum(array_length(value_column, 1)) FROM example_table; // outputs 2
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XJ5AwXvq).

p.s. the `1` parameter in `array_length` specifies the depth to traverse (for nested arrays)